I am seeing a strange thing almost every night, it is very painful and disturbing
AoA, I often see jinns, specifically 2 hours before Azan of fajr. Suddenly In my sleep I hear there's some voice coming saying la ilaha illallah. Slowly this voice getting strange and it disappears. After it suddenly I hear some evil voices. I fear and then suddenly gets up but there's weight on me by which I can get up. I see a black jinn in front of me and my body gets dragged and my right hand gets up automatically. I start to recite Ayat ul Kursi due to which I feel severe headache and feels like someone is pressing my very strongly. During this I'm constantly seen jinn in front of me and I'm sitting but I can't move. I keep reciting Ayat ul Kursi or any ayat which come to mind. Suddenly everything disappears and gets to normal and I'm enable to stand. But still there remains strong pressing of my head and shoulders like someone is still pressing it until some other person see me. It always happens when I'm sleeping alone or everyone around me is sleeping. It's very painful and disturbing. I try to read Quran and offer Nimaz, but strong immediate reactions are shown after nimaz or Quran, Like Yawning and strange pain in my head and body. Please someone tell me what are these things and Why it is happening to me. Also tell me How can I get rid of all these things and return to normal life.

It could be sleep paralysis. Either way this question is not answerable as we are not clairvoyant.

Make sure to do Janabah Qusl if you don't. Also recite Surah al-Falaq (113) ans an-Naas (114) before sleep and make Wudu from time to time specially before sleeping. Reciting "أعوذ بالله من الشیطان الرجیم" and "بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم" is also a major advice in such situations.
